# Which are the most favorited/upvoted Calculus questions and answers?

Tags: discussion

I'm currently learning Calculus, and recently I came across these excellent two questions :

- [Is $\frac{\textrm{d}y}{\textrm{d}x}$ not a ratio?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-frac-textrmdy-textrmdx-not-a-ratio)
- [Chain Rule Intuition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62614/chain-rule-intuition)

Which contained, some of the best and most in-depth explanations I have seen yet. As a mathematics student, majoring in Pure Mathematics, I thought it would be really interesting to see find more questions like this on the Math StackExchange site.

It would be very helpful to anyone learning Calculus (wheter it be Single-Variable, Multivariable, Vector or Tensor)  to be able to take a look at some of the types of questions people ask, and to read through some of the great answers given for those questions.

Is there currently a list of popular Calculus questions (from Single and Multivariable to Vector and Tensor Calculus) asked on Math StackExchange? If so I would be extremely interested in seeing it.

If not please feel free to share some of the best questions and answers on Calculus that you've come across on the Math StackExchange, I'm sure there would be many users interested in seeing them.

Comment: If you're looking for highly upvoted content, you might look at the calculus tag and sort by votecount.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Comment: And of course you can do the same thing as suggested above not only with the [tag:calculus] tag, but also with other tags of your interest, such as [tag:real-analysis] or [tag:multivariable-calculus].

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the comments, if you are interested in some tag, there are several views you can choose.

You said that you are interested in the [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus) tag. When you click on the tag name you get [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus) - to the list of questions which are tagged with this tag. And you can choose one of several tabs to view/sort the questions: newest, featured, frequent, votes, active, unanswered. (Simply by clicking on the tab name near the top of the screen.)

If you hover with your cursor over the tab name, you will be shown a description what the particular tab means. (Similar thing works for many elements of the Stack Exchange UI.)

[image: screenshot showing various tabs]

Since you say that you want to see the most popular questions, the following two tabs seem to be useful for that purpose. (In each case it is debatable whether these criteria in some sense correspond to the question "being most interesting/popular/relevant", but at least there is probably some correlation.)

- [Votes tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus?sort=votes&pageSize=50) show the most upvoted question. So these are the question where users thought that the questions are worth upvoting, which might be some rough criterion whether the question is interesting.
- I think that also the [frequent tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus?sort=frequent) is useful. This tags shows the questions with most links from other posts. This can also be considered in some sense as a criterion which questions are the most relevant. (But this probably corresponds more closely to "most frequently asked" question rather than "most interesting questions".)

---

I am unaware of a possibility to view most favorited questions in a given tag using the user interface. But you can try to use [data explorer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info), as explained, for example, here: [View Most Popular Questions by favorite count / views / votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29405/view-most-popular-questions-by-favorite-count-views-votes/252164#252164). There is certainly a lot of space for improvement, but I have made a very simple SEDE query here: [Most favorited question in a given tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/485968/most-favorited-question-in-a-given-tag?Name=calculus).

Maybe it is worth mentioning that I have used `Tags like '%##Name##%'` as a selection criterion in that query. So if you use it for the tag calculus, the question from [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus) will also be included. But I suppose that for most tags this not problem will not appear, since there are not too many tags with similar names. For example, I guess this will fork fine for [multivariable-calculus](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/485968/most-favorited-question-in-a-given-tag?Name=multivariable-calculus) or [real-analysis](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/485968/most-favorited-question-in-a-given-tag?Name=real-analysis). If you have some experience with SQL and you can create a query tailored to your needs or to the specific tags you are interested in.